# Access xslt encoding UTF-8

Tags: xml, xslt, encoding, utf-8, xml-namespaces

I'm having issues setting up the layout of my extracted data from a Microsoft Access database into XML. I've created an XSLT template that works for 99% of my file, but for two lines:

1) When encoding into UTF-8, it won't show 'encoding="UTF-8"' in the  tag, but if it's encoded in UTF-16, then it will. I need this attribute to be show.

2) I have a tag (let's call it `<tag></tag>`) which has a version attribute as well as a xmlns:xsi attribute. They are set in the correct order in the XSLT file, but are switched in the output file:

XSLT is like:

```
<tag xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="V1.2.3.4 02-09-2013">
```

XML output is like:

```
<tag version=""1.2.3.4 02-09-2013" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

How could I possibly force the XML file to have its content it the exact same way as the XSLT file?

For the record, I use Microsoft Access to export my data, and don't have any other way for doing this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

At the level of the data model used by XSLT, the sequence in which attributes occur is not significant, and XSLT offers the user very little control over it.

Your choices, if your downstream software requires that attributes occur in a given order and your stylesheet processor doesn't preserve attribute sequence on literal result elements, are:

- Write a simple filter to run after the XSLT to put attributes into the desired order.
- Fix the (broken) downstream software by repairing its sensitivity to attribute sequence.